# FullCalendar v3.9.0, event on top gets referenced onclick foreach event on same day

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

We have founds ourselves facing a issue with our implemented fullCaldendar, onclick of any event occuring the same date...it will always open the first event of that particular day.

If I for example click on event 'Andreas Karlsson', the event for 'Alexander Wikman' appears.

[image]

I'm totally new with fullCalendar and this was implemented by a developer no longer available. So I would really appriciate any help. What do I look for that makes every event unique?

Comment: Can't really help you much without a [mre] of the issue - i.e. enough code and data to reproduce the problem. See also the [tour] and [ask]. What I will say though is this isn't the default behaviour of fullCalendar, the clicking should work so I'm going to guess the dev has done some weird customisation which doesn't work properly, or there's something else going on with the data which isn't apparent just from a screenshot.

Comment: `What do I look for that makes every event unique?`...they normally have an ID (either assigned by fullCalendar, or in the event data which was originally passed to it). https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your introduction, first post ever on stackoverflow. I understand that more info is needed for beeing able to come up with any solution. I will look into a example of this issue to share. The strange thing is that this issue only occurs in the 'monthly view' & 'weekly view'..it works just fine in listMonth view.
I will get back more info.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.